# PyQtGraph: different symbols or symbol colors based on value

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I have have a timeseries with discrete values (1-6) that I display in a graph:

```
p.plot(x, y, pen=None, symbol='t', symbolPen=None, symbolSize=10, symbolBrush=(100, 100, 255, 255))
```

I'd like to have a different symbol (or a different symbol color) depending on for each of the differnt states (1-6) of the y value; how can this be achieved?

Comment: use a dict for the mapping: `symbols = {1:'o',2:'t',3:'s',4:'p',5:'h',6:'d'}` and set `symbol=[symbols[i] for i in y]` in the plot call.